# How to show the message (50 of 1000 items loaded) on the UIusing Entity Framework 6 when record is fetched for the first time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The problem is when I am loading all the records at a same time it is taking a lot of time (more than 20 seconds) which is bad user experience. So, I am planning to fetch the 50 records but display the message "50 of 1000 items loaded" for the first time.

I have a button "load more" which when clicked will fetch another 50 records and goes on, on  the each click till all the records is fetched.

I am able to achieve the goal of fetching the record but not able to get the total records available in the table when the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: Can you post some code? It seems like a really simple problem with an easy solution, but I can't help you without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example show us how your loading your 50 items

Comment: Please read [ask] and show some relevant code. All you probably need is `dbContext.Foos.Count()`?

Comment: Almost all paging UIs run a `COUNT(*)` query first followed by paging queries.

Comment: How you display those values depends on the UI stack and how you do data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As multiple comments (also on deleted answers) pointed out that you need to run an explicit `COUNT(*)` query for this. This is simple enough and can be done like this:

```
var itemCount = dbContext.Foo.Count();
```

This will return an integer of the amount of items stored in the table.

**Note:** `dbContext.Foo` is an assumption (and I know what [assumptions make of you and me](https://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-you-should-never-assume-you-know-what-happens-when-you-assume-you-make-an-ass-out-of-ellen-degeneres-61-91-22.jpg)) but OP hasn't/ wont post any code. I will try and watch this question and update this answer once OP posted some code

Comment: Wouldn't `dbContext.Foo.Count();` cause performance issue because we have to make two calls - `one is for fetching the records and another for getting the counts`?

Comment: A minuscule one yes. LINQ to SQL is smart enough that when using `Count` it will only return a number, not the entire dataset. If you are already loading the entirety of your data a second query is not needed, but because you are only loading part of it you need it